# Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error when i add the cookie dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I get the following error

```
Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error
```

Its when i add the cookie dependency that i have the issue.
Here is how i declare my angular app :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'ngCookies']);
```

Its when i add the cookie dependency that i have the issue.
And my html file :

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MEAN Auth</title>
  <!-- styles -->
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.6/yeti/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
  </div>
  <!-- scripts -->
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular-resource.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular-cookie.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./main.js"></script>
  <script src="./services.js"></script>
  <script src="./controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="./chirpApp.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you help

Comment: Why do you load different version of cookies and resource than the actual angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url for cookies script is not correct.

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular-cookie.js

should be

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular-cookies.js

Missing 's'.

I am sure, browser's console should show 404 for the request.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing s at the end,

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular-cookies.js"></script>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/aMhNig8WjWcPbkMAA2nk?p=preview)**